# Loop and Offset to .Find and copy all occurrences

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get this code to copy the whole row in which it finds all occurrences of the Target variable. Then it needs to past it into a new sheet that is known by the same name as the variable. That sheet is already created by a different part of the overall program.

Sub Copy_Data()

```
 Dim NumberofFunctions As Integer
 Dim X As Integer
 Dim Target As String
 Dim Last_Row As Long
 Dim Last_Column As Long

 Sheets("Calculations").Select
 NumberofFunctions = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3", Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count





     For X = 1 To NumberofFunctions
        Sheets("Calculations").Select
        Target = Range("B2").Offset(X, 0)

        Sheets("Raw Data").Select
        NumberofFunctions = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3", Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

       '************This code finds the last row used in the sheet******
        Last_Row = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

        '***********This code finds the last column used in the sheet****
        Last_Column = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column

        '*************This portion of the code finds the occurrences******
          ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("F:F", Worksheets("Raw Data")).Find(What:=(Target), _
                After:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False).Activate


      Next X

 End Sub
```

Comment: You can't use `Find` as your function name, since that's already a function in VBA.  Also, since you're wanting to copy info over, you'll probably want a `Sub` instead of a `Function`.  It looks like you're getting there, where are you having trouble?

Comment: You're going to want `findnext` as well.

Comment: `range("A:A").find` restricts it to just column A.

Comment: Thanks! I just did that and now it if flagging RunTime Error 13 " Type Mismatch" over that portion of the code.

Comment: You need to qualify your sheet objects like you did with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range(`

Comment: When I tell you to do something, think about why. If you don't know, research it or ask. I will wait. Edit: what if I gave you code that erases every file on your computer?

Comment: Not bad. But even if things don't change, how does the computer know what you want? Edit: why did you do `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3"`

Comment: Honestly, because I copied it from another spreadsheet where it worked. I am just beginning to learn syntax at the moment. Previously I have used a Frankenstein coding model of copying and pasting from places I know things worked.

Comment: lol yea, I know that. I am asking you to think about why that is. Edit: it's late on Friday afternoon so I am killing some time before starting my weekend but at this pace, we're not gonna get very far XD Edit: I guess I am the only one on SO who's ever taught so I tend not to just give answers. I rather people work through it.

Comment: As I asked before, `how does the computer know what you want?` To you, it's very obvious what `target` is. Can the computer read your mind? Edit: before you rush to qualify `target`, think about **every other object** in your sheet. Really, think about everything that _you_ take for granted. Edit2: yes, if you ever feel stupid, just think about a computer ^_^

Comment: `Which is starting in B2`. B2 of sheet 10 right?

Comment: `should be in "Calculations"` well, did you tell the computer that? Edit: ah yes, you did with `select`. _My fault._ Don't use `select` do what you did with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3"`

Comment: I am leaving soon. `Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("F:F").Find(` will suffice. Please qualify all objects like `range`, `cells`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I have it structured correctly now. I am getting the "Application defined or object defined error" now thought haha. Have a good weekend.

Comment: `Range("F:F", Worksheets("Raw Data")` I am glad you're not just copy/pasting my code but if you're going to write your own, please understand what you are writing ^_^; That code is bad. You have a good one too.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I have?

Comment: `That code is bad`

Comment: Ah. That makes more sense.